# (MS) SQL Select from Rows Where Value is NOT EQUAL to or BETWEEN the values of Rows Immediately Before and After

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Given the following Dataset;

```
# |   id    ts                val
1 |   1     1/1/2000 00:00    1
2 |   2     1/1/2000 00:00    1
3 |   3     1/1/2000 00:00    1
4 |   1     1/1/2000 01:00    2
5 |   2     1/1/2000 01:00    50
6 |   3     1/1/2000 01:00    2
7 |   1     1/1/2000 02:00    3
8 |   2     1/1/2000 02:00    2
9 |   3     1/1/2000 02:00    2
```

I am trying to identify invalid data. The nature of this data is that a CUMULATIVE ever increasing number should always be recorded.

The errant data row in the above dataset is; Row # 5.

```
# |   id    ts                val
5 |   2     1/1/2000 01:00    50
```

It is invalid because the val of 50 in this row, is NOT EQUAL to either the row before or after that timestamp. 1 or 2

This is clearer if we sort the data by ID, TS

```
# |   id    ts                val
1 |   1     1/1/2000 00:00    1
2 |   1     1/1/2000 00:00    2
3 |   1     1/1/2000 00:00    3
4 |   2     1/1/2000 01:00    1
5 |   2     1/1/2000 01:00    50
6 |   2     1/1/2000 01:00    2
7 |   3     1/1/2000 02:00    1
8 |   3     1/1/2000 02:00    2
9 |   3     1/1/2000 02:00    2
```

Can anyone help me build a SQL select statement to select these 'invalid' rows.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
WHERE <val is not equal to OR BETWEEN the row BEFORE or AFTER>  
ORDER BY ID, TS
```

My desired result is to select Row #5.

```
# |   id    ts                val
5 |   2     1/1/2000 01:00    50
```

Thanks in Advance. I hope I have made sense.

Comment: You have two DIFFERENT examples of the data. The second example has always three rows with the same `id` and `ts`. So, how do you order the data?

Comment: Row #5 is fine from your definition.  I see the problem with row #6.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way to access previous and subsequent data (over a certain ordering). On SQL Server, this is done by  [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)  and  [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql). Something Like:

**EDITED:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,LAG(val, 1, 0) OVER (
            ORDER BY ts
            ) AS PreviousData
    )
    ,LEAD(val, 1, 0) OVER (
        ORDER BY ts
        ) ) AS NextData )
WHERE PreviousData =...
AND NextData =...
```

Comment: Windowed functions can only appear in the `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: @YogeshSharma, true, the above is general  example of a sub query, since the exact query criteria  are not to obvious, at least to me

Comment: I am not familiar at all with LAG and LEAD (I am reading now) but I am unsure as to validity of this statement given Yohesh Sharma's comments

Comment: @AaronGlover, I hope my edit helps, the truth is a I have made no tests

Answer (score 0):

Try correlated subquery which may help you

```
SELECT * FROM <table> T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM <table> T1
    WHERE T1.val <> T.val
          AND T1.val BETWEEN T.val - 1 AND T.val + 1
);
```

Result :

```
#   id  ts             val
5   2   1/1/2000 01:00  50
```

**Note**: The above is for based on the overall question and sample data.

Comment: This is close. but the data is not always incremented by 1.

ie:   for id 1, the first time stamp might be 1, the second could be 30 and the third timestamp could have a value of 1000. It is increasing, but not by a regular amount. It does not simply count 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc.

Therefore; simply adding or subtracting 1 from the val does not determine if the value is not between.

or have I missed the point here?

Comment: @AaronGlover can u add some more sample data & result.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(t.val) over (partition by t.id order by t.ts) as prev_val
      from t
     ) t
where prev_val not in (val, val + 1);  -- NULLs are filtered out too
```

This is not exactly the description that you give, but it seems the most sensible based on the overall question and sample data.